# Predict Value Not In Data Set

Tags: machine-learning, classification, ml.net

Given that I have training and testing data, that may be missing a logical sequential number. Is it possible to infer a value that wasn't present?

For example:
Training / Testing Data have values 1,2,3,4,5...7,8,9,10 specified for the label.

Is it possible that based on the data model, that it could predict a result of 6 even though there has been no instance of such an occurrence within the training or testing data?

I am new to Machine Learning and have read about Supervised / Non-supervised learning. It's been difficult to pinpoint an explicit answer, as it's quite hard to get the correct terminology to an area I am unfamiliar with.

Would be be best to create a arbitrary row in the data set that contains a label value that is not present?

Using ML.net.

Apologies if this is a simple question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved, or in fact mitigated, the lack of a value was to do the following. For each input data type that requires to be sequential - no gaps, I only used data / rows from my data set where there was an unbroken sequence, across all entries.

Given the following: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9

I only used data that conformed to the largest available sequence across all entries. 0 - 7. This could lead to some lost data for the training models, but as the data is fairly consistent, there are few omissions.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem about deterministic vs probabilistic approach? I don't get exactly why you should use Machine Learning but try to read Markov Chain:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: Hi Alano, my problem is deterministic for a set of different variables / features. I am going to create several models based on focus areas. Each focus area will have stages where I start to introduce more variables. These together will hopefully give me a probabilistic result, for one label / score. I started to train and test models with a large set of variables / features and found that it was too confusing for the prediction - is this over-fitting? Instead I aim to create a bigger picture based on smaller portions, and might weight these. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a **classification** problem, the 'Label' is the index of the 'true class'. If no examples in the training dataset belong to class '6', then the learned model will never predict class 6: it was taught never to do this.

In a **regression** problem, the 'Label' is the 'quantity to predict' (a real number). In this case, it's very normal for the model to predict the value that it hasn't seen at training time: the model may predict 6, or 5.7 or 6.1 etc.

Without more details, I cannot tell whether you are solving a classification or regression problem.

Comment: It is a classification problem, desertnaut removed part of the title for some reason unbeknown to me. Originally, the title was: Machine Learning - Classification - Predict Value Not In Data Set. But this might have broken some house.

Thanks you Zruty, it seems that classification will fail unless there is a precedent set. I think it will be more suitable to use a regression model, I thought that regression models were more about what comes next. I aim to find predicted integer based outcomes. I could round predicted score to the nearest, but also could take into account